# How to prevent wifi router from broadcasting multiple ssids?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ssid

I have the following Wi-Fi router: http://www.beetel.in/business-solutions/international-business/adsl/450-four-port-wifi-modem

And I am also posting screen shots of ISP settings (from 192.168.1.1). Problem is, my Wi-Fi router is broadcasting multiple SSIDs (even the SSIDs which I used in the past and aren't entered in settings at present).

How do I resolve this to broadcast single SSID? I have already tried factory settings restore.

### SSID1 Settings

[image]

### SSID2 Settings

SSID2 Settings- greyed-out, unable to change anything
[image]

Comment: Are you able to edit configuration when selecting other SSID in `SSID Index` drop down menu?

Comment: no, i am not able to configure any option on ssid index 2 page. i can only select ssid index to go back to ssid1 and am able to configure all the settings for ssid1

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to disable it by modifying the settings file of your router.

1. Go to “Maintenance -> Update -> Backup/Restore” and save the settings of your router on a file.
2. Copy the settings file (just in case you make a wrong change)
3. Open it in WordPad or some other editing program.
4. Search for MGMNT
5. change this text above MGMNT: `N="DISABLED" V="0x0"  N="SSID" V="MGMNT"` to `N="DISABLED" V="0x1"  N="SSID" V="XXXX"` and save the file.
6. Upload the new settings file on the router by going to “Maintenance -> Update -> Backup/Restore” and select load from settings file.
7. Upload and your router should restart without MGMNT SSID.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on an Upvel router which seems to use the same interface as your beetel.

Your router automatically broadcast X number of SSID's. Mine broadcasted 4 with default names of riger 0, 1, 2, 3 respectively.

To change the settings of the other 3 and hide them you must click on their index numbers individually, and save the page before switching index numbers again.

So riger_0 index number is 1. riger_1 is 2 and so on.

Hopefully this is still useful to you a year later.

Answer (score 0):

use a wired connection. i think router disables ssid2 because you are connecting to the client using the second connection. if not, connect to the wlan over the first connection and disable others by changing "ssid index" on that form